# Simple script functions only when placed in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xmlhttprequest

Here is some code that works. The HTML is a simple select element. The script populates it with JSON data from a call.

home.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="id01"></div>
    <select id="machines"></select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "blahblahblah.com/api/getmachinetypes";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                myFunction(myArr);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(arr) {
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $('#machines').append('<option value=' + arr[i].Id + '>' + arr[i].Name + '</option>');
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

However, when i remove the script and place it in test.js, the select list no longer populates. Why is this?

home.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="id01"></div>
    <select id="machines"></select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

test.js:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "blahblahblah.com/api/getmachinetypes";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('#machines').append('<option value=' + arr[i].Id + '>' + arr[i].Name + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried nesting the entire script in $(document).ready, but that didn't work, and i'm pretty sure it isn't needed because xmlhttp.onreadystatechange should already be firing when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "blahblahblah.com/api/getmachinetypes";

function myFunction(arr) {
        var i;
   for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('#machines').append('<option value=' + arr[i].Id + '>' + arr[i].Name + '</option>');
    }
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: I tried your solution twice but it still didn't work.  Great idea though, I didn't think of considering the order given the order worked in one instance but not in the other.

Comment: are you getting the responseText?

Comment: try : console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) before JSON.parse

Comment: Here's the console output:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://preview.c9.io/patrick_motard/test_space/test.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: That's what it was! The js file was in a folder that i didn't include in the src. Thank you! Can't believe I didn't catch this!